# Why would an 'a' tag with href defined not be clickable?

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

Why would an 'a' tag with href defined not be clickable, that ids wen you point on the pointer doesn't change and the link is not clickable? below is the actual code using Materialize css,

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">

  <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
    <li><a class="black-text" href="mymenu.html">My Menu</a></li>
  </ul> 

</div>

.navbar-fixed {
  position: relative;
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 997;
}

.navbar-fixed nav {
  position: fixed;
}

.black-text {
  color: #000000 !important;
}

side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
  height: 100%;
  height: calc(100% + 60px);
  height: -moz-calc(100%);
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow-y: auto;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-105%);
          transform: translateX(-105%);
}
```

Comment: And css for that part is....

Comment: CSS can be used to change the pointer, Javascript can be used to suppress the click handler.

Comment: @Thilo CSS can also be used to suppress pointer events ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Values

Comment: Have you made sure you havent got another element (perhaps with position: absolute;) covering it? What does Chrome's inspector say when you right click in the element?

Comment: If you are still having problems, add **ALL** of the CSS and JavaScript related to that element to your question.  If I paste what you provided into a snippet, it is clickable.  Something you are not showing us is causing the issue.

Comment: Yeah, we need a snippet to work with the info we've been given.

Comment: Looks okay with what you provided. http://codepen.io/asim-coder/pen/zoZvme

Answer (score -1):

you can use the next code:

```
li{
  cursor:pointer !important   
}
```

The important marker is not really necessary but it is to prevent, because I don't know if you are using bootstrapt or another similar framework. Try and coments your results!

Good luck!

Comment: What problem does this fix, and how?